# Wordpress won't let me use a page slug of 'feed'

Tags: rss, feed

I want to make a custom feed page* with the slug of 'feed', but when I try to save, Wordpress changes it to 'feed-2'.

Is there a way I can force Wordpress to let me use a slug of feed—or, if it's better practice, to hook my custom feed template* into the default Wordpress RSS feed generator?  If the latter, what code do I need to substitute my own feed template for the default?

* The custom feed template I'm using is based on the useful code here: http://digwp.com/2011/08/custom-feeds/

Comment: Just change the slug name. 'feed' is a reserved word (you should respect that). So get over it. LPT1 is a reserved filename in Windows. I got over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because "feed" is a [reserved term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) (actually [wp_unique_post_slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) will match your page name against the rewrite rules).

You might be able to change this by removing the WP feed on `init`:

```
unset($GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->feeds[array_search('feed', $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->feeds)]);
```

(maybe flush the rewrite rules after)

Comment: The only thing is I am using regular WP-generated feeds for other sections of the site. This looks like it would prevent those as well.